# How to analyze and improve performance of C++ library running on arm (Android)?

Tags: android, c++, optimization

I want to optimize a speech processing library for Android (arm) to make it fast enough for real-time processing. I compile the library already with compiler optimizations (e.g. -O3 -ffast-math -ftree-vectorize...) but that doesn't help, so I need to optimize the code itself.

What is the best way to analyze a C++ library running on Android? Important measures would be for example:

- Floating point operations in methods
- vectorizations in methods
- ...

Comment: There 2 kind of optimizations: you can either optimize your mathematical assumptions and algorithm (and this is the best optimization that requires time and analisys) and tool optmiziations like flags. If you define the bottlenecks to eliminate - then there is a big chance to choose the right way: the first or the second.